# Awesomium Disable Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable Awesomium's keyboard shortcuts as the `Backspace` `F5` and so on.

What i already tried with no luck...

```
private void Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Try PreviewKeyDown to get it beforehand.

Comment: you can't handle a key before it is fired so i can't call `e.Handled = true` in the PreviewKeyDown...

Comment: I mean there must be a good straightforward way to do such thing, especially that Awesomium is not only used as a Webbrowser but also as  a HTML UI engine so how would a UI accept Backspace and refresh calls!